# Refresh output per character, not per line

Tags: ssh

My program prints out a `.` (without newline) every 100 ms to indicate progress.
When running it on a remote machine via ssh, however, I cannot see the output before a newline is printed.
I tried it on Cygwin and on Ubuntu.

Is there a way to make ssh display output before the line is complete?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is usually output buffering by your program, or more accurately by an IO library or run-time that your program uses. Specifically line-buffering.

Unbuffered IO is much less efficient, which is why it is not used by default.

Programming languages often have a way of specifying unbuffered output. Since it usually depends on what STDOUT is connected to it is also affected by OS environment settings.

See also [stdbuf](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/stdbuf-invocation.html)

Comment: Awesome! prepending `stdbuf -o 0` to the command did the trick. Thx